# What film or show depicted a character being sucked out into space

Tags: story-identification, horror, space

I know this is extremely broad, but I have a vivid memory from childhood (mid 80s to early 90s) of a scene set inside a spaceship.  Two characters, I think perhaps in spacesuits, perhaps a romantic couple, are clinging on for life as the atmosphere in the room is sucked out into the vacuum.  One of the characters slips and vanishes into space just before something large blocks the open door.

I remember being quite terrified as a child, but I don't recall any other details.

Comment: There is a continuous decompression trope page http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ContinuousDecompression but it doesn't seem exhaustive and I can't see anything that matches your description

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. This is already pretty generic, and there are already two answers that fit, and likely quite a few more.

Comment: OK but neither of the answers match the description I gave.

Comment: Just to say...it's not *sucked* into space....it's **blown** into space.

Comment: Some things are better left unsaid.

Comment: You could also say that when we drink cola the weight of the atmosphere is *blowing* it into our mouths.

Answer (score 2):

If you were growing up in the UK, then it could have been [Blake's Seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blake%27s_7), a staple of Saturday early evening TV. There is an early episode called Space Fall where one of the antagonists (Raiker) is sucked out into space.

You can read the original script [here](https://archiveofourown.org/works/5929102). There also seems to be a full length video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpqQPKjs27o). The scene you want is at about 50 minutes in.

Comment: Thanks but the scene I recall saw two characters clinging on as the air and debris was sucked out of a room.  The opening was then blocked by something large like a table after someone had been sucked out into space.

Answer (score 1):

There's a scene like this in the awful, terrible, just bad Wing Commander movie. (seriously, I saw it at the dollar theater and asked for my money back).
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0131646/
It is LATE nineties however.

Comment: I would have been in my teens by then, so it can't be that.